# Populating urls into a div from separate directory with Javascript/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url

My goal is to have users upload photos to a directory in the root called "userupload". All this folder will contain is .jpg images.

I now want to call ALL the image paths from "userupload" directory to a different .php page into a div called "content" like so:*`<p><img class=resizeme src="userupload/uploadimage1.jpg"></p>`*

**I found this script and I have only been able to return the image file name.. which is fine, but i don't know how edit the code to place it in the correct path.**

*"This will list all jpg files in the folder you define under url: and append them to a div as a paragraph. Can do it with ul li as well."*

```
$.ajax({
  url: "useupload",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
        // will loop through 
        var images = $(this).attr("href");

        $('<p></p>').html(images).appendTo('#content')

     });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted seems to rely on the webserver being configured to return a directory index listing for the `userupload` folder (thus may not work on a different webserver – the proper way to do it on the server-side is what Joseph Silber suggests). The listing consists of links to relative urls.

Considering that what you have already is working, and that all of your images are under `userupload`, a simple change inside your `.each` loop should do the trick:

```
var images = 'userupload/' + this.href;
$('<p><img class="resizeme" src="' + images + '"></p>').appendTo('#content');
```

---

*Considering your comment that you're getting* `src="userupload/mysite.com/uploadimage1.jpg"`:

```
var images = 'userupload/' + this.href.split('/')[1];
$('<p><img class="resizeme" src="' + images + '"></p>').appendTo('#content');
```

Comment: Thanks bfavaretto.. I am almost there.. the script you just gave me is returning 

"<img class="resizeme" src="userupload/http://mysite.com/uploadimage1.jpg"/>"

How do i get it to remove the "http://mysite.com/" from the middle of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the PHP you could use:

**image_listing.php**:

```
<?php

$imageLinks = array();
$dh = opendir("userupload");

while ( $file = readdir($dh) )
{
    $tempArray = explode(".",$file);
    if ( isset( $tempArray[1] ) && $tempArray[1] == "jpg" )
    {
        array_push( $imageLinks, 'http://example.com/userupload/' . $file );
    }
}
closedir($dh);

echo json_encode( $imageLinks );
```

This will return an array of links, which you could then use in your JavaScript:

```
$.get('image_listing.php', function (array) {
    $.each(array, function(){
         $('#content').append('<p><img class="resizeme" src="' + this + '"></p>');
    });
});
```

This is a quick example which works, but you should probably build an HTML fragment (instead of hitting the DOM each time in the loop):

```
$.get('image_listing.php', function (array) {
    var container = $('<div'>);
    $.each(array, function(){
         container.append('<p><img class="resizeme" src="' + this + '"></p>');
    });
    $('#content').append( container.html() );
});
```

Comment: "This is a quick example which works, but you should probably cache that selector, and build an HTML fragment (instead of hitting the DOM each time in the loop)."

Can you please elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: @user1787325 - Every time you run `$('#content')`, jQuery has to query the DOM to find that element for you, which comes at a performance cost. Additionally, it's never a good idea to `append` HTML in a loop, since every interaction with the DOM comes with a performance hit. Instead, you can create an element in memory (outside the page's DOM), and append your `<p>`'s to that. Then, once you've built all your elements, append them all to the DOM in one fell swoop. I've added some sample code to my answer.